# Writing in a CSV file row-wise in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to read the name of all of the 'mp4' files in a directory and I need to write the name of each of them in the rows of a csv file. But the problem is that all the names are written in different columns. How I can fix that?

```
import csv
import os
Names = []
path_and_label =[]

for file in os.listdir("/mnt/storage/user/kinetics400/train_256/abseiling"):
    #path_and_label =[]
    if file.endswith(".mp4"):
        full_address = os.path.normpath(os.path.join("/mnt/storage_6TB/user/kinetics400/train_256/abseiling", file))

        

        path_components = full_address.split(os.sep)
        
        Label = path_components[6]
        path_and_label.append(full_address + ' ' + Label)
        
        
        with open('/mnt/storage/user/kinetics400/my_kinetics.csv', 'w+', newline ='') as f:
    
            writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')



            writer.writerow(path_and_label)
            
            

f.close()
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not resetting `path_and_label` to a new blank list for each file, so it just keeps accumulating more and more file info.  Try putting `path_and_label =[]` inside the loop.

Comment: Also, when you open the file in `w+` mode each time through the loop, it erases the previous contents.

Comment: @JohnGordon , Thanks for the comments. When I added 'path_and_label' inside the loop, only one path is written inside the csv file (I also changed 'w+' to 'w').

Comment: are you taking label from the mp4 file name?

Comment: @NavaneethaKrishnan, In this case, the 'Label' takes the 'abseiling' from the path of a video.

Comment: `w` and `w+` both erase the existing file contents.  You'll either have to open the file in `a` mode, or (even better) only open it once, before the loop, instead of opening and closing it many times inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. try the below code. I am not sure what you trying to print with Label=path_component[6] that's I have commented out that part.

```
import csv
import os
Names = []
path_and_label =[]

all_files = os.listdir("G:\\")    
csv_files = list(filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.mp4'), all_files))

with open('.\\theResultfile.csv', 'w+', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n')
    for file in csv_files:
            #path_and_label =[]    
                full_address = os.path.normpath(os.path.join("G:\\", file))
                path_components = full_address.split(os.sep)
            # Label= path_components[6]
                print(path_components[1])
                path_and_label.append(path_components)
                print(path_components)
                writer.writerow(path_components)         
print(path_and_label)
```

Above code writing below results into csvfile

[image]

Code for recursive search into Path.

```
import csv
import os

searchDirPath = 'S:\\'
searchFileExt = '.txt'
searchResults =[]

with open('.\\theResultfile.csv', 'w+', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, lineterminator='\n')
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchDirPath):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
             searchResults.append(os.path.join(root, file))
             print(os.path.join(root, file))
             writer.writerow(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Thank you for the working answer. Actually, I have a main folder and inside that there are a lot of folders with specific names (abseiling, dancing and etc that these folders' names are considered as labels (I mean 'Label' variable that you commented out in your answer )). In the example that I posted, the whole videos are located in the folder of abseiling but I need to do the aforementioned task for whole videos that are located in different folders with different label names. How I can generalized the solution following the mentioned scenario?

Comment: You need to use "import glob,os" and recursive = true. I will update the answer with the example code.

Comment: I have done this using OS.Walk instead of using glob